# Is a Chi-squared test sufficient to tell me if my process change was "good enough"?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, experiment-design

**Experiment Design:**

**Process**: Outputs the order in which to do the work (assumption: ordering of work items is most preferred/valuable by stakeholders)

**Work items**: The process above produces a rank ordering of items. Individual teams select work items from this "prioritized" queue to do their work.

I introduced a new process to perform the prioritization and we did notice some improvement in the selection of work items i.e., work items were more and more goal oriented and not as per "whims of individuals" or "star performers" only.

**Question to answer**: Given 4 year experimental data I wish to know if my 'new' process was any better?

**Current Approach**: For a set of work-items I compute how strongly did their selection/choice compare with the prioritization ordering of the new/old process. I compute a correlation metric (almost like an exam score in essence) which is a weighted average of the proportion of work-items completed. For example:

- Percentage of top 25% work items completed * $w_1$
- Percentage of 2nd 25% work items completed * $w_2$
- Percentage of 3rd 25% work items completed * $w_3$
- Percentage of bottom 25% work items completed * $w_4$

Weights are chosen as $w_1 = 8, w_2 = 4, w_3 = 2, w_1 = 1$ That is if highest priority tasks are selected we wish to give that a higher score. Weights are normalized on $[0,1]$. A simple coverage metric, like $10/22$ items done, would not do justice. Also 100% of the tasks can never be completed, since that makes the prioritization redundant, but it's good if that's the case, albeit rare. I create three categories based on the scores: *Strong, Medium and Weak* if the scores are $> 0.5,[0.2, 0.5), < 0.2$, respectively.

I performed a Chi-squared test as follows, based on the frequency counts of Strong/Medium/Weak correlations as above. The DV is the work-item-selection and the IV is the Prioritization Process.

$H_0 = $ work-item-selection is not impacted by process change

$H_1 = $ work-item-selection is impacted by process change

[image]

I conclude there's a high chance that the new process has impacted work item selection rejecting $H_0$ and accepting $H_1$.

**Questions:**

1. Is this approach correct and are the inferences drawn from it valid?
2. Is $\chi^2$ the best that can be done given the above DV/IV? Are there any other tests? Would they add more value to the insight gained from $\chi^2$?

**Note**: For simplicity we are considering only one IV since most of the other variables is what we controlled for keeping them almost constant (i.e., team size/composition etc.,) and we (people reviewing this experiment) have agreed that they don't impact the DV and can thus be removed from the model.

Comment: Is the question of interest "is the new one better, no matter by how tiny an amount, as long as it's more than could be explained as random variation?" or is it more "how much better is it? Is it enough to really say we made a difference?". The second is really about measuring an effect (and would lead to say an interval estimation exercise rather than a hypothesis test).

Comment: @Glen_b - Ideally, the latter if possible, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that. Could you please elaborate on the interval estimation? I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: For example, one might construct confidence intervals on the changes in the proportions in your table, or a confidence interval for the mean of your weighted-metric.

Comment: Would that just be it? Nothing more?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you're after with that last question - what things you look at depends on your needs/questions of interest. I think it directly addresses the question you seem to want to answer, but if there are additional considerations of interest, there's nothing stopping you looking at additional things. Perhaps if you clarify that question further I can give a better response.

Comment: No that's fine. I was surprised at the trivial solution. Hence the element of surprise :)